# How to Generate rgb code given an integer

Tags: javascript, rgb

I need to generate an rgb between two colours given an integer. For example, genRgb(73) will give me an rgb code between (255, 0, 0) and (0, 255, 0) based on the parameter 73.5. So 0 would correspond with (255, 0, 0), and 90 would correspond with (0, 255, 0).

I tried something like this:

```
function toColor(num) {
    var b = 0
    if(num < 60) {
        var g = num
        var r = num/2
    } else {
        var r = num
        var g = num/2
    }
    return "rgba(" + [r, g, b].join(",") + ")";
}
```

but all the rgb codes ended up looking pretty similar, and it's not a very smart solution.

I would appreciate any help with this. Thanks

Comment: what output do you expect 73.5 to produce?

Comment: Something in between the (255, 0, 0) and (0, 255, 0). I don't think i explained myself well, but i need the numbers to correspond to an rgb code between those two. I don't know how exactly. So 73.5 would be more green than red.

Comment: _"given an integer"_ ... _"73.5"_  one of these things is not like the other

Comment: Sorry, i meant float...

Comment: @etarhan yeah like that

Comment: @etarhan then 0 = `rgb(255,0,0)` and 100 = `rgb(0,255,0)`?

Comment: And why is it just red and green? @IbrahimFadel

Comment: @stwilz that is how I understood it at least, not sure

Comment: yeah, so  0 = rgb(255,0,0), 100 = rgb(0,255,0), and 50 = (122, 122 0)

Comment: `const toColor = num => "rgba(" + [(255 * (1 - num / 90)) | 0, (255 * num / 90) | 0, 0].join(",") + ")";`

Comment: so, now it's 0 to 100??? it was 0 to 90 in the question ... the first step to solving the issue is to *define the requirement* and stick to it

Comment: I thought you said `90 would correspond with (0, 255, 0).` where did `100 = rgb(0,255,0)` come from??

Comment: The value of blue is always 0?

Comment: @JaromandaX your answer worked really well, thanks

Comment: This is extraordinarily confusing color combinations. Can you please explain how the number corresponds to the RGB code?

Comment: why would half way be 122,122,0 ... 127,127,0 surely

Comment: @JaromandaX indeed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Notice when num = 0,  r = 255 & g = 0. While the value of num increases, the value of g also increases. But the value of g decreases. So we can proceed in this way.

```js
function toColor(num){
    var r = 255 - Math.floor(255*num/100);
    var g = Math.floor(255*num/100);
    var b = 0;

    return "rgb(" + r + "," + g + "," + b + ")";
}

console.log(toColor(0));
console.log(toColor(50));
console.log(toColor(73.5));
console.log(toColor(100));
```